# nslookup return different values

Tags: amazon-ses, cname, dkim, nslookup

I have the following situation about dkim records

I've added som dkim records (CNAME) for aws domain validation.

When performing nslookup mydkimhost I receive server can't find host:NXDOMAIN

But if I type nslookup -q=CNAME mydkimhost the value of my CNAME record is returned.

Can anyone tell me why is this behaviour happening.

I have other cases where both commands return the same answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Taking a deep look to the returned values, I found that the command with CNAME on it, was not returning the correct value of the dkim record. That was why the nslookup didn't found the server. Correcting this issue solved the problem.

BTW, the value was added correctly, but the dns administrator, for a reason I still don't know, was adding the domain to dkim record.